# How to use the value returned by the SUM() function in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use the value returned by the SUM() function in sql inside my IF statement. I can't seem to assign a declared variable to have its value after using it.

For example, I used SUM() to add 5 columns in a table and returned 5. I wanna use that 5 value in the condition of my IF statement:

IF *sum_return_value* = 5 THEN

*statement*

Is there a way of doing it? I'm using oracle sql developer

Comment: You will need to show your code to better explain what you want to do.

Comment: `IF` statements exist in procedural languages such as PL/SQL. Are we talking about PL/SQL here? If so, please add it as a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a PL/SQL solution, it could look like this:

```
DECLARE
   total: NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(A) INTO total FROM MY_TABLE WHERE B = 37;
  IF total = 5 THEN
    ... do something ...
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I tried using your code:

DECLARE
   total: NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(quantite) INTO total FROM histomvts WHERE mvtident = 85117;
  IF total = 0 THEN
    UPDATE histomvts
    SET opcvm = 16977
    WHERE mvtident = 85117;
  END IF;
'END;'

Answer (score 0):

Try this. first declare **sum_return_value**

```
SELECT SUM(column) INTO sum_return_value FROM table;

BEGIN
   IF sum_return_value =5 THEN
     --do something
   END IF;
END;
```